# Whats the relation between resonances observed in the transmission curve, and the density of states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

How are the oscillations observed in a T(E) curve related to the density of states? Do we observe the oscillations when there's a larger density of states at that particular energy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.